# How to set up a new database in Postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm attempting to work out how to set up PostgreSQL for my django project and am struggling with using the shell to create the database (on windows).

In lots of tutorials I've seen the commands to input but they don't seem to work with what the shell I have accepts.

When I load the shell it gives me:

```
Server [localhost]:
```

Then whatever I input it follows with,

```
Database [postgres]:
Port [5432]:
Username [postgres]:
Password for user postgres:
```

Then exits.

It seems as if it is trying to connect to a database but I can't work out how to create a new one that I will be able to connect my django app to.

Any advice on how I'm using PostgreSQL wrong and what to do to solve this would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you opening the shell?

Comment: From the start menu, name: SQL Shell (psql)

Comment: Try running `psql` from a new command prompt to see if you can catch the error.

Comment: It asks for a password - doesn't seem to be the password I supplied when installing postgresql or my user password - any ideas on what it may be asking for?

Comment: Try `psql -U postgres` and enter the password you set up the database with.

Comment: I have a similar issue, but the last solution provided by Rob - psql -U Postgres - unfortunately, does not work in my case. I shall be glad for another workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I 'm not sure if it will help you. Watch this video: https://youtu.be/AzheRKRS6eo?t=108. It shows how to install the postgre database through the ubuntu.

Example from the video:

```
sudo -u postgres psql

CREATE DATABASE myproject;
CREATE USER myprojectuser WITH PASSWORD 'password';
ALTER ROLE myprojectuser SET client_encoding TO 'utf8';
ALTER ROLE myprojectuser SET default_transaction_isolation TO 'read committed';
ALTER ROLE myprojectuser SET timezone TO 'UTC';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE myproject TO myprojectuser;
\q
```